# FirebaseUser.isAnonymous() always returns false after profile update (Firebase 10.2.0)

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't know what can go wrong here. I want to know if a user is signed in anonymously. I use `signInAnonymously()` for signing in. Everything works like a charm. But a call to `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().isAnonymous()` always returns false. I verified in the firebase console, that the user id is actually anonymous.
What can go wrong here?

**.:EDIT:.**
updated code - added code for profile update - added code for anonymous user initialization

```
public final void initiateAnonymousSignIn(@NonNull final String displayName, @Nullable final Bitmap avatar) {
    onRegistrationProgressStarted();

    Task<AuthResult> signInTask = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signInAnonymously();
    signInTask.addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                AuthResult result = task.getResult();
                FirebaseUser user = result != null ? result.getUser() : null;
                if (user != null) {
                    Log.d(getTag(), "Signed in anonymous user is "
                            + (user.isAnonymous() ? "anonymous." : "not anonymous."));
                }
                UserService.isLoggedInWithAnonymousUser();

                onRegistrationProgressFinished(true, null, AuthProvider.ANONYMOUS, displayName, avatar);
            } else {
                // Wrap FirebaseExceptions for better error handling.
                onRegistrationProgressFinished(false, wrapFirebaseException(task.getException(), null),
                        AuthProvider.ANONYMOUS, displayName, avatar);
            }
        }
    });
}

public void initiateUserAfterRegistration(@Nullable final String newDisplayName, @Nullable final Bitmap newAvatar) {
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    if (user == null) {
        onUserLoadingFinished(null, DatabaseError
                .fromException(new Exception("Can't initiate user after registration. User is not signed in.")));
        return;
    }

    if (newDisplayName != null) {
        Task<Void> updateTask = updateProfile(user, newDisplayName);
        updateTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                // proceed anyway, no matter if the profile could be updated or not
                loadUserAndUpdateOrCreateIfNeeded(newDisplayName, newAvatar);
            }
        });
    } else {
        loadUserAndUpdateOrCreateIfNeeded(null, newAvatar);
    }
}
```

Profile update:

```
private Task<Void> updateProfile(@NonNull FirebaseUser user, @NonNull final String displayName) {
    UserProfileChangeRequest profileChangeRequest =
            new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder().setDisplayName(displayName).build();
    Task<Void> updateTask = user.updateProfile(profileChangeRequest);
    updateTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "User profile updated successfully with new display name: " + displayName);
            } else {
                Log.w(TAG, "Could not update user profile with new display name.", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });

    return updateTask;
}
```

UserService.java

```
public class UserService {

    public static boolean isLoggedInWithAnonymousUser() {
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current user is " + (user.isAnonymous() ? "anonymous." : "not anonymous."));
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Current user is null.");
        }

        return user != null && user.isAnonymous();
    }

}
```

And this is the unexpected output I get:

```
03-19 01:48:38.385 6553-6565/com.myapp D/FirebaseAuth: Notifying listeners about user ( JCPHPVtShAf4QCPSUAYghteP2l32 ).
03-19 01:48:38.386 6553-6553/com.myapp D/FirebaseApp: Notifying auth state listeners.
03-19 01:48:38.386 6553-6553/com.myapp D/FirebaseApp: Notified 1 auth state listeners.
03-19 01:48:38.388 6553-6553/com.myapp D/LoginActivity: Signed in anonymous user is anonymous.
03-19 01:48:38.388 6553-6553/com.myapp D/UserService: Current user is anonymous.
03-19 01:48:38.956 6553-6553/com.myapp I/UserService: User profile updated successfully with new display name: asasdsd
03-19 01:48:39.143 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 25031
03-19 01:48:39.143 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Using measurement service
03-19 01:48:39.143 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
03-19 01:48:39.145 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Activity paused, time: 11362503
03-19 01:48:39.146 6553-6588/com.myapp I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
03-19 01:48:39.147 6553-6588/com.myapp D/FA: Logging event (FE): _e, Bundle[{_o=auto, _et=25031, _sc=LoginActivity, _si=-7803740637554967126}]
03-19 01:48:39.152 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Using measurement service
03-19 01:48:39.152 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-19 01:48:39.161 6553-6553/com.myapp D/Events: Registered AFragment
03-19 01:48:39.161 6553-6553/com.myapp D/AutoManageHelper: onStart true {0=com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaaa$zza@c70c388}
03-19 01:48:39.163 6553-6553/com.myapp D/MainActivity: onResume()
03-19 01:48:39.163 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Using measurement service
03-19 01:48:39.163 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
03-19 01:48:39.163 6553-6588/com.myapp V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 11362522
03-19 01:48:39.195 6553-6553/com.myapp I/MainActivity: onAuthenticated()
03-19 01:48:39.195 6553-6553/com.myapp D/UserService: Current user is not anonymous.
```

Notice the **update of the display name** after the login and the **non-anonymous user after that** (at the end of the log). Is it maybe a bug where the anonymous state is not in sync after a profile update?

Comment: Can't reproduce your results when running with 10.2.0.  Are you using a different version of the SDK libs?

Comment: Confirming 10.2.0

Comment: Confirmed in my code. Seems to be exactly the bug described in the question.

Comment: So the actual problem is that `isAnonymous()` returns false after a profile update.  Post the code for the profile update.

Comment: I've added some code.

Comment: that's right, there's no anonymity on the internet

Comment: @Sarge Borsch you're disqualified XD

Comment: I filed a bug at https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/

Comment: @BobSnyder any progress on this?

Comment: @cybergen: Not sure what you mean.  I have not looked at this further.  I'm not associated with Firebase or Google, so don't know the status of your bug report.

Comment: That still seems to be an issue. Any progress? If i `signOut()` and then `signInAnonymously()` everything is OK but if i `signInAnonymously()` when still sign in, the `isAnonymous()` is not being updated